# CMake multiple projects using same library

Tags: cmake

What's the practice in CMake to build (not at once) multiple projects which use same library? As far as I know in CMake people tend to use subdirectory approach. But library can't be a real subdirectory of multiple projects without library source duplication. There's also a top-level CMakeLists.txt approach but I don't think this is a good solution as you have to create that for every project and it must be one level up of project directory which doesn't play well with source control (like GIT) where you would like to have single repository/directory for single project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually found an acceptable solution here:
http://www.mail-archive.com/cmake@cmake.org/msg39062.html
It is somehow similar to the idea of specifying upper level directory in `add_subdirectory` but doesn't pollute project's CMakeLists.txt file, instead passes dependent project paths by CMake arguments. This way project's CMakeLists.txt file seems to obey ordinary CMake subdirectory hierarchy. I must say that it feels a bit wrong that CMake somehow forces us to use subdirectory hierarchy but I don't know all the reasons behind this, so probably it's fine.

Answer (score 1):

CMake is a crossplatform make tool to "make" a project including the contained subproject. Thus either a source is part of this structure or not. But IMHO cmake is not the tool to manage all the projects within one  major project tree.

My approach is to setup independent projects. Every project builds the lib, tests, documentation and installs it into the project store. In the case one of these libraries is required by an other library or application, it is referenced in the cmake file of that project.

Thus the releases of the projects are independent, projects are smaller and can be combined as required.

I use a script to build all my libraries an the application. But this can be replaced by cmake to.

- Let the build of the most top project depending on the build of the libraries
- Add custom commands into most top project to trigger the build of referenced lib.

Possible solution:

```
add_custom_command(TARGET myapp PRE_LINK
                   COMMAND cd /mypath/libA && mkdir build && cd build && cmake ../source && make install)
add_custom_command(TARGET myapp PRE_LINK
                   COMMAND cd /mypath/libB && mkdir build && cd build && cmake ../source && make install)
add_executable(myapp ${SOURCES})
```

Comment: I agree with you about using multiple projects, that was what I meant. "Every project builds the lib" - but how can it build library if it's not placed in subdirectory of project? I can't place same library source in multiple projects. Is it a bad practice to "fool" CMake by using following add_subdirectory call to include library into project build?: `add_subdirectory("${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../common_library", "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../common_library/build")`

Comment: AFAIK it is not possible to leave the cmake tree (last tried some versions ago). But why not `cmake` + `make` + `make install` the base library. And then include **find_library mylib** or **find_package mypackage** in the depending CMakeLists.txt? Have you alreday find_library out?

Comment: My project uses lots of libraries and I want to build them all at once not each one separately and think about dependencies myself. Approach with add_subdirectory works at least from the first sight but it feels a little bit contradictory to CMake :) Don't know what you meant by "Have you alreday find_library out?", I don't have to use find_library if I build with add_subdirectory.

Comment: I use a script which performs the build steps over all libraries in the right order. But your are right - this is handmade.

Comment: Thanks! The thing that I don't like with custom commands or using script is that you have to manage library location & includes by yourself. Also with top level approach and subdirectories there exist problems which I mentioned in my initial question - library code duplication or artificial top level CMakeLists.txt which doesn't belong to any repository.

Comment: I think I will stick with add_subdirectory(<dir at same level>...) approach/hack because then you can specify interface and library location in library CMakeLists.txt and in other projects you can just call `target_link_libraries(proj, lib)` and it will add includes and library automatically.